# Analog inputs showing value even there is nothing connected to it

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

After watching something weird on the serial monitor I wrote a simple code to monitor the analog pin input values. There was nothing connected to the analog pins still they where showing decimal representation of some analog values.

the code is

```
float ana [] = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5};
float dec [6];  

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{ 
  for(int i = 0; i<6 ; i++)
  {
    dec[i] = analogRead(ana[i]);
    Serial.println(dec[i]);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

How is this even possible?

this is the output result

[image]

Comment: You have an array of 6 analog pins, but are reading from 7.

Comment: It was a mistake.. i corrected it

Comment: read the docs https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/ section "Notes and Warnings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is floating if nothing is connected.  It is reading whatever random noise it happens to pick up.  That's what it is supposed to do.  For it to read 0 it would need to be connected to ground.  Google "floating input" for more info.